# How to recover java folder in NetBeans 8.0>Tools>Templates

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-8

I accidentally deleted the java folder in Tools -> Templates in NetBeans 8.0. Now it does not show me the option to make a Java class. I reinstalled netbeans, but it did not help.

Could you please help me to recover it?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Close NetBeans IDE, go to [NetBeans userdir](http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqWhatIsUserdir), then to `config/templates` directory and delete `Classes_hidden` file.

When NetBeans IDE is started again templates for Java are back.

Answer (score 0):

An easy to recover your Java template is to go to Tools->Templates and delete another template at random (say the HTML one) then click the Revert to Default button at the right and your HTML and Java templates will be recovered.

P.S. I'm guessing you were trying to remove that author:  thing in the template, so a good way to do that is by going to Tools->Templates->Java->Java class->Open in Editor and you can modify freely your template.