# Im missing main class in NetBeans

Tags: java, netbeans

I accidentally deleted main class in NetBeans from Templates, know I cannot create any projects.
Does anyone know how to retrieve it?
I tried to reinstall NetBeans but it didn't work for me.
So please if anyone knows how to fix this I would appreciate  it very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look here. Same problem resolved.

UPDATE

Ok.
Close NetBeans IDE, go to [NetBeans userdir](http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqWhatIsUserdir)
, then to config/templates directory and delete Classes_hidden file.

When NetBeans IDE is started again templates for Java are back.

[From here duplicate post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24833350/how-to-recover-java-folder-in-netbeans-8-0toolstemplates)

p.s Net beans user dir is something like this
C:\Users\YOUR_USER\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.2\config\Templates
I tried this and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Netbeans automatically updates your work when you clean and run. Just:

1. open your project
2. Go to project History / History
3. Select a period that the project worked correctly before deleting the main class
4. Right click and revert from History